"Quedársele a alguien" as "recordar"
A few dictionaries (notably not the RAE) note that "quedársele a alguien" can be used as a synonym for "recordar" or "retener información."

No se me queda la lección después de haberla aprendido.
Está muy mayor, no se le quedan las cosas.

This seems to be a regionalism. I have asked some Spaniards about this, some from Galicia and others from Madrid, and they gave mixed responses. Those from Madrid were most comfortable with this use. The Mexicans I asked were not at all. One Salvadoran friend told me it seemed perfectly fine. Is it understood where this use of quedársele is common, and is there a reason why it isn't included in the very expansive definitions in the RAE?
Sources:
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/quedarse
https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/quedarse
https://dle.rae.es/quedar

At least in Argentina, we do use "quedarle a alguien" to mean "to remain in sb's memory", but we don't use the pronoun "se": quedársele a alguien. I agree that DRAE does not specifically cover that usage to refer to something being kept "in somebody's memory".

@Gustavson So do you say "Está muy mayor, no le quedan las cosas"? If we have just "No le quedan cosas", how can you distinguish between not having things and not retaining things in memory? Also do you think that is really necessary to specify that as a separate meaning?

Yes, we do say that, "no le quedan las cosas, no le quedan los nombres, no le quedan las fechas", to mean he/she does not remember them. I think that meaning should be specified. Notice that if we replace "quedar" with "permanecer" or "persistir", the meaning in question is not conveyed: ?No le persisten/permanecen los nombres/las fechas. I think DRAE should have included that as a separate meaning or use.

Curiously, DRAE also lists “quedarSE” as a synonym of “permanencer (en un estado/una condición).” When you read the definitions of quedar, #5 makes no mention of the pronominal use. However, I understand that when it comes to something remaining in a place or condition, quedar is more common with inanimate objects and quedarse is more common with people. When changing states, “quedar” seems to be closer to “to end up/to wind up…” and quedarse is closer to “to go…” I wound up hurt -> Quedé herido. I went to sleep -> Me quedé dormido.

@Gustavson Sure, you can't replace the verb directly, you're right. But have you heard about "memoria volátil"? I think that such term applies to computers, humans or animals. And permanente (permanecer) and constante are antonyms of volátil. If the lesson is not there, it's absent (ausentarse). For me all these elements are mentioned in the meaning that I quoted in my answer.

One deleted answer mentioned that "quedar" as "Retener una cosa en la memoria" is explicitly mentioned in the Diccionario María Moliner but it seems that there is no on-line version of such dictionary.

Well, I think DRAE should include one such definition, including "en la memoria" (permanecer en la memoria / persistir en la memoria). Notice that when you say "Me quedó esa información", "en la memoria" is understood.

@RubioRic Segun DMM: "("con") prnl. Retener una cosa en la memoria: "Me quedé con la matrícula del coche." (https://www.ellibrototal.com/ltotal/?t=16&d=710859). It looks like they have a definition for quedarse con algo but not quedársele a alguien, interesting.

@SebastianPojman-Malo But that's the definition that you're looking for. I don't get the difference. Is not the same?

Son similares, pero supongo que tecnicamente "No me quedo con las cosas" es diferente de "no se me quedan las cosas a mi."

I've come to realize that the verb "quedar" is indeed an interesting case depending on the subject it takes.
While María Moliner brings up this meaning:

17 ("con") prnl. Retener una cosa en la memoria: "Me quedé con la matrícula del coche".

here, as stated in a deleted answer and in an OP's comment, there is another pattern (definitely much more usual where I live) in which the subject of "quedar" is the thing being remembered. Therefore, here we would never say the above (which we would use for retaining something physically, even by inappropriate means) to mean "remember" and would instead say:

Me quedó la matrícula del coche (the car license plate number remained in my memory).

(The sentence above could also refer to the car license plate remaining in my possession, but does not convey the possibly illegal connotation of "Me quedé con la matrícula del coche", which could be interpreted as somebody keeping it against the legal owner's will).

I'm not sure if it's a regionalism. In any case, I think that we use it that way in Andalucía, Spain.
Why do you think that the meaning is not covered in the DRAE?
For me it corresponds to the first meaning listed there

quedar

intr. Estar, detenerse forzosa o voluntariamente en un lugar. U. t. c. prnl.

Sin.:  permanecer, estar, afincarse, establecerse, ubicarse, arraigar.
Ant.:  irse, marcharse, ausentarse, partir.

I've highlighted one of the synonyms: permanecer

permanecer

intr. Mantenerse sin mutación en un mismo lugar, estado o calidad.

Sin.:  mantenerse, quedarse, continuar, durar, seguir, estar,
persistir, perpetuarse, conservarse, resistir. Ant.:   cambiar.

I've highlighted another synonym above: persistir
This verb, persistir (to persist) is commonly used in IT to reflect when a value is stored successfully in a database, a non-volatile memory storage.
So it's perfectly fine and understandable using "quedar" when you're not able to retain, to persist in your brain, what you have learned. And that meaning is covered in the DRAE as you can see.

Quedársele a alguien algo. El chico no consigue recordar las fechas de cumpleaños de sus amigos, no se le quedan las fechas. La estructura es: Sujeto (las fechas) + pronombre se + pronombre de complemento indirecto + verbo quedar en tercera persona. Significa “memorizar, recordar”. This is a very normal sentence in Spanish.
